# How to align two form buttons on the same line and tell which was clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a form which as two buttons: cancel and submit

Here is an example page: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=228

If you log in with this login: testing@problemio.com / testing

and then click on the comments tab, you will see some options to edit some of the comments.  If you click edit, you get a form. How do I place the submit and cancel on the same line?  And how do I k know which of the buttons was clicked?

I try to tell with this:

```
$('#add_comment').live('submit',function( )
{
    alert($(this).val());
        ...
```

But that code doesn't output anything for me.

Or maybe in case they press cancel another function can be called altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: This would be much easier if you just posted your HTML in a fiddle, rather than making us log in, then jump through hoops to find the problem page.

Comment: @Rory I have not been using the fiddle thing because I am worried I have too much html/js and php things mixed in.  Also this way you can reproduce the error and see on your own.

Comment: I followed your instructions and couldn't even find the page you were talking about. We don't need to see the entire code, just the relevant bits of HTML/CSS that are causing your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons don't submit, they click. Forms submit. Just use type="button". You can give the button an ID and read it back as an attribute.

```
$('#add_comment').live('click',function( )
{
    alert($(this).val());
    alert($(this).attr('id')

        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

can't you just bind to the click event handler of your cancel button and stop the event propagation, after doing your thing?